# Display short domain (country code) in the address bar while still having the site served on a global .com

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have 2 domains let say redd.it and reddit.com.

Now how might I let google index the reddit.com but have users browse redd.it?

The purpose of this would allow the address bar to be shorter and automatically give the users a shorter domain(although not technically a url shortner) while allowing Google to use reddit.com for indexing and Google links.  As explained [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922?hl=en) it appears country code extensions are penalized(not exactly but being ccTLD certainly hurts you results outside your specific country).

They only way I could see this working is 2 sites with duplicate, but I'm not quit sure if this would work.  Would duplicate sites decrease ratings for one or the other site?

How might I display a short domain in address bar while indexing and displaying the reddit.com link on Google?

Comment: I am not sure what the payoff would be in doing this. What would be the advantage?? None that I can imagine. It only buys you confusion and unnecessary complication with no gain that I can see. BTW- there is no ccTLD penalty - they are limited to the regions where they are designated to work. I am not sure how they fit into you scheme. Can you make your purpose for this clearer??

Comment: @closetnoc Google states `Sites with country-coded top-level domains (such as .ie) are already associated with a geographic region, in this case Ireland. In this case, you won't be able to specify a geographic location.` Basically you are right although I'm not sure if you read the link because you can't change country code target therefore there is a penalty in some sense although that might not be the exact term.  A ccTLD vs a gTLD has a penalty.  The positive is that the domain is shorter(what other use is there for country code domains outside using it in your own specific country).

Comment: Be careful in using the term penalty. Just because a ccTLD is designed to be to be geo-targeted and a gTLD is not, does not mean that a penalty is being applied. Far from it. It just means that they are doing what they are designed to do. If you want a shorter domain name, then I suggest using one. Trying to have both does not make sense to me. Simplicity always wins. Especially in search.

Comment: @closetnoc I will probably just use a .com domain.  Except it is not simple in this case.  It is far from it.  I would understand if all ccTLD domains acted like you described but they don't.  They are 15 or so domains that are treated as gTLD which is silly(.it is not one of them).

Comment: Actually it is the other way around. The are gTLDs that, because of domain name hacks, are being considered as gTLDs. I do not agree with it, but popularity in use trumps original intent. Fundamentally, search is simple, but there is a lot of moving parts. You only need to worry about a few of the major parts to perform well. I remind people that despite the advances in search technology, search engines remain old-school and that following the evolutionary timeline and tradition without following the SEO lemming experts daily gyrations goes a long way.

Comment: @closetnoc I think there is a typo here I don't seem to understand your intent "The are gTLDs that, because of domain name hacks, are being considered as gTLDs."  An example of such is .me which is ccTLD which is treated as gTLD.

Comment: Yes you are right. My bad! The are *ccTLDs* that, because of domain name hacks, are being considered as gTLDs. Like I said, while the hack is cute and all, I am not in favor of breaking such a large design rule simply because it is funny. I do have a sense of humor though... I do like the hacks... I am not sure I would have moved the ccTLDs into the gTLD camp for plain 'ole fun. Personal opinion. Call me a Scrooge if you want. ;-)

Comment: I would be concerned that Google may not like what you are trying to do. Google does check websites external from its networks to ensure that what Google see is what a user sees. I am not sure if you would heading in that direction even with good intentions. (Which I am very sure you have.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the `.com` domain automatically frame itself using the `.it` domain.  You would maintain a parallel set of URLs.   So `page.html` would have:

- `http://example.it/page.html`
- `http://example.com/page.html`

On `example.it` you would have a simple frameset that would:

- Include the content from `example.com`
- Use the actual page title
- Have a rel canonical link tag to direct search engines to the correct thing

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Full page title</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href=http://example.com/page.html">
</head>
<frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="//example.com/page.html">
    <noframes>
         <a href="//example.com/page.html">Click here to continue</a>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

---

The `.com` site would:

- Include JavaScript to frame itself

  ```
  try {
      if (top.location.href != "http://example.it/page.html"){
          top.location.href="http://example.it/page.html";
      }
  } catch (e){
      // Can't access top location, must be in a frame set
  }
  ```
- Have all links point to the `.com` site so that search engines can follow them easily
- Include a `base` tag in the `head` so that all links break out of the frameset by default

  ```
  <base target="_top">
  ```

Comment: I do not like frames of any kind, but they are a reality these days and this seems like a totally viable solution. Very clever!!

Comment: Yes and you should be able to use `history.pushState` in HTML5 browsers to change url.

Comment: @LiamWilliam From the [Mozilla pushState documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method): "The new URL **must** be of the same origin as the current URL; **otherwise**, pushState() will throw an exception."

Comment: As far as I know, nothing like this has ever been tried on a real site.    You should consider this to be an experiment.   Google may not view your site as a global site even with this frame in place.   It also may detract from user experience because it may lead to longer load times, or inopportune refreshes and flashing.   You also may get some stats double counted.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I left the comment on this post to try and make it clear that you should combine the 2 approaches.  It would take some doing but either with an iframe(onload parameter or something else or server trickery on backend you could use pushState and AJAX to prevent flickering.

Comment: My question now would be "Is there a way to mark 2 different sites with duplicate content as the same for google bot indexing"  would this be better fit as a new question or edit?  That was within the scope of my original question but it has been edited by others and doesn't fit great as is.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference between reddit.com & redd.it, If it is your real domain names are short like this.
Assume that you have a length domain which you want to display with short URL.

IMO, All the effort what you are doing is not worth it. (Yes, I have 15+ years of expr).

Let me share how can it be done.

You can allow the googlebot to crawl the .com site and then in .htaccess redirect the users to .it website. Though this is strictly not allowed in google. **it will result in your website being penalized. So do not do it**

> The purpose of this would allow the address bar to be shorter

Looks like you are concerned about the short address bar,But really user does not bother about the length of your domain name, unless you have more than 100 character domain name.

You can put this effort on something which will give better result.

Comment: Keep in mind that Google does check for cloaking by accessing the site external from the Google network. A cloaking penalty will come quickly when discovered and is not one that can be recovered from easily or quickly. It may take years in fact. As you rightly said, Google will penalize the site. I only mentioned this because so many do not know that checking for cloaking is very routine and cannot be detected.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. Perfectly valid warning. I made up for it some at least.